# HitTest property

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I'm new to silverlight and trying to read a silverlight tutorial that uses HitTest method to know when the mouse is over a control.
But unfortunately i cant see any method with this name.

Where is the HitTest method? is that because i'm using silverlight 4? is there any replacement method ?

Comment: What tutorial are you trying to follow?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Older versions (pre 3.0) did have a HitTest method.  In Silverlight 3 and 4 you ouwl use the 
`VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates` method to acheive a similar goal.

For example the following code could be used in a mouse event on surface over which you might be dragging an item. It will determine if any part of the dragged item overlaps the target item.  *Warning air code*

```
var container = (UIElement)sender;
var transform = draggedItem.TransformToVisual(container);

Rect rect = new Rect(transform.Transform(new Point(0, 0)), 
   new Size(draggedItem.ActualWidth, draggedItem.ActualHeight);

bool hit = VisualTreeHelper.FindElementsInHostCoordinates(rect, container)
  .Any(elem => elem == targetItem);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.mouseenter%28VS.95%29.aspx

You can subscribe to those events and set a flag which indicates that the mouse is over your element, or do whatever else your application needs.

Comment: i'm building a demo application that you can drag and drop a control wherever you want in the form except on a circule control(exist in the form).In the tutorial  they use circule.HitTest(e.GetPosition(null)) where e is the "MouseEventArgs".What happened to this method(hitTest) why i cant use it?